# Odoo `--test-enable` doesn't work

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm following `Odoo 10 Development Essentials` Chapter 2 to develop a simple todo addon. I'm using odoo's docker as my environment.

You can check all my source code (including dockers') at https://github.com/spacegoing/docker_odoo

The problem is I set up my `tests/` directory exactly the same as the book's example. However, the test only run once. After the first execution the test was never invoked. There is even no `.pyc` file in `tests` directory.

Here are the commands I tried

`odoo --db_host db --db_port 5432 -r odoo -w odoo -i todo_app --test-enable --xmlrpc-port=8070 --logfile=/var/log/odoo/odoo_inst1.log`

`odoo --db_host db --db_port 5432 -r odoo -w odoo -u todo_app --test-enable --xmlrpc-port=8070 --logfile=/var/log/odoo/odoo_inst1.log`

Notes:

1. `odoo-bin` is `odoo` in docker
2. I've installed `todo_app` with another `odoo` instance running on port `8069`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. This is the hugest **gotcha** I've ever met since I'm 5 years old.

## No where mentioned in official document that `test` **will only run** after you installed the `demo database`.

I found this from this forum post: 
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/why-my-test-yaml-do-not-run-42123

So if you tried every single command you can find and none of them works, this might be your answer.

Comment: This appears to hold true still. Although I've only tested on Odoo 9.0 so far.